# Validation of whitepsace separated integers c++

Tags: c++, validation, input, integer, cin

I have seen other questions on SO in regards to validation of the format of input however am looking for a more specific answer for the issue i am having.

Currently, I am required to read in 2 integer values and store them as coordinates. I have used:

`cin >> x >> y`

which will read the values of x & y in separated by a space.

However, any input other than a

> int *whitepsace* int

will destroy my program. I have attempted to validate the input to ensure each value is an integer however it only applies to the first integer input.

I also need to ensure that the format of the input remains as *int whitespace int* so that i can consistently use the values throughout my program.

Any ideas?

Things i have tried with no luck:

- Reading using a do - while loop w/ `cin.fail()` and `max()` checks.
- Validating using `isDigit()`

Comment: Please clarify whether it is always the end of the line after the second integer; and what exactly you mean by "the format of the input remains as int whitespace int" ? Do you mean that you want to preserve the exact whitespace that occurred between the two ints in the input file? Also, what do you want to happen when the input does not match the expectation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the two values into two `std::string`s first. This will read in any whitespace-delimited text, without putting `std::cin` into a failed state.

Once the two words are read in, for each one construct a `std::istringstream`, use `operator>>` to attempt to parse it into an `int`. Use `fail()` to check whether the conversion failed, or not, and if the entire `std::istringstream` was consumed.

If the `std::istringstream` is not in failed state, and `get()` returned `eof`, then the entire word was succesfully parsed into the `int`.

Problem solved.

This is not, of course, the only way to do it, but is probably the most simple one, and the approach is limited to using basic C++ library classes, nothing too fancy.

Comment: I was going to raise an issue - but i managed to figure it out myself. Thanks for this. Really appreciate it!

Comment: This is one of those rare cases where I sometimes revert back to the good ol' `scanf` series of functions with a `FILE *`, and don't feel bad about it.

Comment: @JasonC `cin >> x >> y` and `scanf("%d %d", &x, &y)` are very similar in their error handling requirements

Comment: @M.M It's the separate checking of `fail()` that bums me out. But like you say it's just a small difference. It just rubs me the wrong way, for no real reason. I do like that `scanf("%d %d", &x, &y)` tells you which one fails.